# Error al enviar .zip en un webservice (https)

Tags: java, android, webservice, ksoap, xmlhttprequest

Estoy enviando un archivo (.zip) a una webservice utilizando ksoap

```
public static SoapObject uploadLogZipAndSend(File fileToSend, String nombre, String descripcion) {

    SoapObject request = createNewRequest("subiendo");

    createAndAddProperty("archivo", null , FunctionsUtil.fileToByteArray(fileToSend), request);
    
    return androidCallToWS(request);
}
```

Método:

```
private static PropertyInfo createAndAddProperty(String name, Class type, Object value, SoapObject request) {
    try {
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = new PropertyInfo();
        propertyInfo.name = name;
        if (type != null)
            propertyInfo.type = type;
        request.addPropertyIfValue(propertyInfo, value);
        return propertyInfo;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        FunctionsUtil.ShowMessage(e.toString());
        return new PropertyInfo();
    }
}
```

Método:

```
private static SoapObject createNewRequest(String requestName) {
    return new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, requestName);
}
```

Método:

```
private static SoapObject androidCallToWS(SoapObject request){
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = null;
    

try {
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        new MarshalBase64().register(envelope);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        //androidHttpTransport = createHttpsTransportSE();
        androidHttpTransport = crearhttptransport();
        //generateInfoLog(getPropertiesInfoForLog(request));
        getPropertiesInfoForLog(request);

        if (androidHttpTransport != null) {
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            androidHttpTransport.call(NAMESPACE + request.getName(), envelope, generateHeaders());
            return envelope.bodyIn != null ? (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn : null;
        } else
            return null;
    }
    catch (SSLPeerUnverifiedException | SSLHandshakeException exception) {
        SoapObject exceptionObject = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, CLASS_NAME);
        exceptionObject.addProperty(ERROR_MESSAGE_TAG, exception.getClass().getName());
        //generateExceptionLog(exception);
        FunctionsUtil.ShowMessage(exception.toString());
        return exceptionObject;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        //generateExceptionLog(e.getMessage() + "\n Respuesta del servidor: " + androidHttpTransport.responseDump);
        FunctionsUtil.ShowMessage(e.toString());
        FunctionsUtil.ShowMessage(e.getMessage() + "\n Respuesta del servidor: " + androidHttpTransport.responseDump);

        return null;
    }
}
```

Y tengo este error.. no llega ni a la webservices.

El error es justo en:

```
androidHttpTransport.call(NAMESPACE + request.getName(), envelope, generateHeaders());
```

Error:

> org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT The page was not...@1:68 in java.io.InputStreamReader@70da275)

Les comento mis pruebas:

| En mi local con https | En mi local con http | En mi servidor con https | En mi servidor con http |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| funciona correcto.. logro enviar el .zip y llega a la webservice. | logro enviar el .zip y llega a la webservice. | me manda el error org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT The page was not...@1:68 in java.io.InputStreamReader@70da275) | logro enviar el .zip y llega a la webservice. que puede estar pasando! |

> **Dato:** Si no envió un zip .. y por ejemplo envió una imagen (jpg) .. si logro enviarlo .. que sucede?

Gracias!